# Drawing a polygon of polygons

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes, polygon

This question is vagely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449433/selecting-cards-to-form-a-fair-game?noredirect=1#comment7090962_3449433. I am trying to visually illustrate the ways one can draw 3 balls from a pile of `N+M` balls,
where `N` is the number of blue and `M` is the number of green.

My attempt at doing this in tikz can be seen below. Here I first
arrange the balls in order, and then show how they appear when one ball is removed. A line between two balls indicates that these two balls are choosen PLUS the dotted ball.

[image]

There are some changes I would like to do however.

1. So we pick 3 balls, the two connected by the line PLUS the dotted one. 
   If these three balls have the same color, I want the line connecting them to be in style X (dashed, or red or etc)
2. If the three balls have different colors, I want the line connecting them to be in style Y (solid line, orange, or etc)
3. Why does my code fail for the particular case `2`?
4. Is there a way to make the code work for different number of blue and green balls?
5. How can I pick the rotation of the center polygon so that it matches with the corners of the outer one? Now I changed the inner one to manually fit.
6. Is there a particular reason the code below does not work?

   ```
   \foreach \x in {1,...,\n}{
     \begin{scope}[shift={(b.corner \x)}]
       \missingPentagonTemp{2}{c};
     \end{scope}
   }
   ```

Here is what I want it to look like (courtesy of paint).

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\usepackage{ifthenx}

\newcommand{\missingPentagon}[2]{
    % draw edges
    \node[draw=none, minimum size=3cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = \n] (#2) {};

    \def\n{6}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\start}{int(min(#1+1, \n))};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\stop}{int(max(#1-1, 2))};

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{
         \foreach\x in{2,...,\n}{
            \foreach\y in{\x,...,\n}{
                    \draw[color = black, dashed](#2.corner \x)--(#2.corner \y);
            }
        }

        \foreach \x in {1}{
          \draw[fill=green!20,dashed](#2.corner \x) circle[radius=1em] node {\x};
         }

        \foreach \x in {2,...,\n}{
          \draw[fill=blue!20](#2.corner \x) circle[radius=1em] node {\x};
        }

    }{

        \foreach\x in {1,...,\stop}{
            \foreach\y in {\x,...,\n}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\y}}{}{
                    \draw[color = black, dashed](#2.corner \x) -- (#2.corner \y)};
            }
        }
        \foreach\x in {\start,...,\n}{
            \foreach\y in {\x,...,\n}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\y}}{}{
                    \draw[color = black, dashed](#2.corner \x) -- (#2.corner \y)};
            }
        }

        \foreach \x in {1}{
          \draw[fill=green!20](#2.corner \x) circle[radius=1em] node {\x};
         }

        \foreach \x in {2,...,\n}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\x}}{
                \draw[fill=blue!20,dashed](#2.corner \x) circle[radius=1em] node {\x};
            }{
                \draw[fill=blue!20](#2.corner \x) circle[radius=1em] node {\x};
          };
        }

}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\n{6}

\node[draw=none, minimum size=3cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = \n] (a) {};

\node[draw=none, minimum size=10cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = \n] (b) {};

\foreach \x in {4}{
  \draw[fill=green!20](a.corner \x) circle[radius=1em] node {1};
 }

\foreach \x in {1,...,3}{
    \pgfmathparse{int(\x+3)}
  \draw[fill=blue!20](a.corner \x) circle[radius=1em] node {\pgfmathresult};
}

\foreach \x in {5,...,6}{
    \pgfmathparse{int(\x-3)}
  \draw[fill=blue!20](a.corner \x) circle[radius=1em] node {\pgfmathresult};
}

%\foreach \x in {1,...,\n}{
%  \begin{scope}[shift={(b.corner \x)}]
%    \missingPentagonTemp{2}{c};
%  \end{scope}
%}

\begin{scope}[shift={(b.corner 1)}]
    \missingPentagon{4}{c};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(b.corner 2)}]
    \missingPentagon{5}{c};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(b.corner 3)}]
    \missingPentagon{6}{c};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(b.corner 4)}]
    \missingPentagon{1}{c};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(b.corner 5)}]
    \missingPentagon{2}{c};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(b.corner 6)}]
    \missingPentagon{3}{c};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attempt to answer the question with a `pic`. This code checks whether or not a vertex is in the list of missing or highlighted vertices (yes, you can use lists now) and draws the edges accordingly.

As for your points:

1. Done.
2. Done. At this point the style is is solid. One can change it.
3. Honestly, I did not try to think through the code. Sorry.
4. Yes. Now these are lists.
5. Changed. One may also just rotate the polygon, but I like mod conditions. ;-)
6. Again, I did not try. Sorry.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{memberQ}{2}{%
  \begingroup%
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpb{0}%memberQ({\lstPast},\inow)
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpa{#2}%
    \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i#1\pgfmath@token@stop
    \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tmpb}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup}
\def\pgfmath@member@i#1{%
    \ifx\pgfmath@token@stop#1%
    \else
      \edef\pgfutil@tmpc{#1}%
      \ifx\pgfutil@tmpc\pgfutil@tmpa\relax%
      \gdef\pgfutil@tmpb{1}%
      \fi%
      \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i
    \fi}        
\makeatother
\tikzset{circ/.style={circle,minimum size=2em,draw},
pics/missing polygon/.style={code={
   \tikzset{missing polygon/.cd,#1}
   \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/missing polygon/##1}}
    \node[draw=none, minimum size=\pv{size}, 
        regular polygon, regular polygon sides =\pv{n}] (-poly) {};
    % test if the highlighted node is in the missin nodes
    \edef\lsthigh{\pv{highlight}}
    \foreach \XX in \lsthigh
    {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ktest}{memberQ(\pv{miss},\XX)}
    \xdef\pgfmathresult{\ktest}}
    \edef\ktest{\pgfmathresult}
    \foreach \XX in {1,...,\the\numexpr\pv{n}-1}
    {
     \foreach \YY in {2,...,\pv{n}}
     {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{memberQ(\pv{miss},\XX)+memberQ(\pv{miss},\YY)}
      \ifnum\itest=0
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jtest}{memberQ(\pv{highlight},\XX)+memberQ(\pv{highlight},\YY)}
       \draw \ifnum\jtest=0 [dashed]\fi \ifnum\ktest=1 [solid]\fi
       (-poly.corner \XX) -- (-poly.corner \YY);
      \fi
     }
    }   
    \foreach \XX in {1,...,\pv{n}}  
    {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{memberQ(\pv{highlight},\XX)}
    \ifnum\itest=1
     \node[missing polygon/highlighted] (-poly-vertex-\XX) at (-poly.corner \XX){\XX};
    \else
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jtest}{memberQ(\pv{miss},\XX)}
     \ifnum\jtest=1
      \node[missing polygon/missing]  (-poly-vertex-\XX) at (-poly.corner \XX){\XX};
     \else
      \node[missing polygon/regular] (-poly-vertex-\XX) at (-poly.corner \XX){\XX};
     \fi
    \fi
    }
}},missing polygon/.cd,size/.initial=3cm,n/.initial=6,
miss/.initial={2},highlight/.initial={1},
highlighted/.style={circ,fill=green!20},
missing/.style={circ,fill=blue!20,dashed},
regular/.style={circ,fill=blue!20}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\n{6}

\node[draw=none, minimum size=3cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = \n] (a) {};

\node[draw=none, minimum size=10cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = \n] (b) {};


\foreach \X in {1,...,\n}{
  \pgfmathparse{int(1+Mod(\X-4,6))}
  \draw \ifnum\X=4 [fill=green!20] \else  [fill=blue!20]\fi
   (a.corner \X) circle[radius=1em] node {\pgfmathresult};
}

\path foreach \X in {1,...,\n}
{ [/utils/exec=\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mymiss}{int(1+Mod(\X-4,6))}] 
    (b.corner \X) pic(m\X){missing polygon={miss={\mymiss}}}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this looks fantastic. Never knew about lists! Regards to the lower left one it would be great if all the lines were solid, and the circle around the 1 should be dashed (minor detail). Btw I tried to keep the dashed circles towards the center, any particular reason you did not? (I am still digesting your great code)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar OK, I updated accordingly.

Comment: I updated your code slightly, so that it better fits my aim. Rollback if you are not happy. I only changed the mod part to change where the dashed balls appear =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Thanks!